# Is parse_ini_file returning data always in same order of given file?

Tags: php, parsing, ini

Are the key value pairs returned by parse_ini_file() always in the same order of the used ini file it was parsing from?

I'm also wondering if I will get always the same ordered array when using it. So looping over the result array will be always in the same order on every system and php versions 5.6+?

Comment: Try it and see?

Comment: Trying it on my own system can not ensure that the behaviour is always the same. I didn't found information about that in the documentation